# PHP: Format an array

Tags: php, arrays

Some PHP-Variable on my website is set with an array.

The `print_r($array)`-command gives this out:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Lorem Ipsum
            [REX_MEDIA_1] => wave01.png
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Test
            [REX_MEDIA_1] => background.jpg
        )

)
```

Now i would like to format the array-output. For each value there should be something like this:

```
<div style="background:url(REX_MEDIA_1);"><p>name</p></div>
```

Which is the best way to do something like that?

Comment: `foreach` loop is your "friend"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `foreach` and then print what you want

> The foreach loop works only on arrays, and is used to loop through
>   each key/value pair in an array.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        echo "<div style='background:url(".$value['REX_MEDIA_1'].");'><p>".$value['name']."</p></div>";
    }
```

Here you have a [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp) where you can learn more about `php loops`

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to loop through the array:

```
foreach ($array as $v) {
    echo '<div style="background:url(' . $v['REX_MEDIA_1'] . ');"><p>' . $v['name'] . '</p></div';
}
```